# Add URLS from a Django App

Tags: django, django-urls

I'd like to add URLs from a Django app I'm adding within settings.py 
I've tried adding **urls.py** in the hopes it would work but it doesn't 
 (because it only reads *the project/project/urls.py* and not *project/app/urls.py*)

How can I make the app add urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include) function, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^some_base_url/', include('your_app.urls')),
                       )
```

Including other urlconfs is [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Comment: Could not import your_app.urls. View does not exist in module your_app.

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with a url defined in your app. @samu's answer is correct. I hope you're replacing `your_app` with the name of your django app...

Comment: yes of course, do I have to import something on app/urls.py OR project/urls.py ?

Comment: project/urls.py is the one that django uses, so you have to import *to* project/urls.py. Which means, that you have to state your imports in project/urls.py. The imported urls.py file must also define a *valid* urlconf, named urlpatterns.

Comment: I think I had to restart the server (plus forgot the include), works now!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to `import include` from `django.conf.urls`. Your in your **project urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^SOME_BASE_URL/', include('APP_NAME.urls')),
                       )
```

This assumes you have some URLs defined in your **app urls.py** as well.

For example, for a class-based generic view to appear at `/SOME_BASE_URL/`, your app's **urls.py** would look something like the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import SomeView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', SomeView.as_view(), name='some_name'),
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to go to the urls.py file of your project.
There you need to import include along with path.

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

Add URLs patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('cv/', include('app_cv.urls')),
]
```

Note: app_cv is my app.
That link will take you to the urls of app_cv.
Now also add urls in your app. Inside your app create the file named urls.py. In that file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.index)
]
```