# Trouble with urls mapping to view functions in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to group all of my URLs within my todo list app into the project/todolist/urls.py file. So I have a button and a String field where you can add the item to the list, and when you push the button it should send the string to the data model and redirect back to the homepage with the updated list. This works when I have all of the urls placed in the project/urls.py file like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('todo_list/', include('todolist.urls')),
    url('addItem/', addItem),
    url('deleteItem/(?P<i>[0-9]+)', deleteItem)
    ]
```

But I wanted to use the include() function instead and group all of the add, delete and todo_list views into a single file in project/todolist/urls.py. But when I do this I get Page not found errors and such:

```
Using the URLconf defined in test_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    todo_list/

The current path, addItem/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Below is the code that is throwing the error. I have tried to change things in the html template so that the form action goes to `/todo_list/addItem/` instead of `/addItem/`, but this for some reason doesn't solve the problem.

*** project/todolist/urls.py ***

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_todo),
    path('addItem/', views.addItem),
    path('deleteItem/(^?P<i>[0-9]+$)', views.deleteItem)
    ]
```

*** project/urls.py ***

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('todo_list/', include('todolist.urls')),
    ]
```

*** project/todolist/views.py ***

```
def get_todo(request):
    """Function performed when we open the homepage"""
    # our model allows us to get items from the DB into the view
    
    # get all current items from the DB
    all_todo_items = TodoListItem.objects.all()
    logging.debug(all_todo_items)
    # create empty form where new items can be added
    form = TodoForm()
    
    # we always want to display the empty form and the list of todo items
    todo = {'todo': all_todo_items,
            'form': form
            }
    
    return render(request, "todo.html", todo)

@csrf_exempt
def addItem(request):
    """Function performed when we click the submit button"""
    logging.debug(print(request.POST))
    form = TodoForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        new_item = TodoListItem()
        
        new_item.content = form.cleaned_data['todo']
        new_item.save()
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo_list/') 

def deleteItem(request, i):
    """Function when we click delete button"""
    #item = get_object_or_404(TodoListItem, pk=i)
    item = TodoListItem.objects.get(id = i)
    item.delete()
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo_list/')
```

*** project/todolist/templates/todo.html ***

```
<h1> ToDo List </h1>


    <form action="/todo_list/addItem/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <div>
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add Todo Item">
      </div>
      
    </form>


    <p> 
        Current List:
        
             <ul>
                 {% for item in todo %}
                   <li> {{ item }} </li>
                   <form action="/todo_list/deleteItem/{{item.id}}" method = "post">
                       {% csrf_token %}
                       <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                   </form>  
                {% endfor %}
            </ul> 
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar functionality I recently built and I think in your template you should use this:

```
<form action="{% url 'deleteItem' item.id %}" method = "POST">
```

And to use **include** you will want this I think:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^some_base_url/', include('your_app.urls')),
                   )
```

Found here [Add URLS from a Django App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614960/add-urls-from-a-django-app)

I think the django docs explain this pretty well if you want to have a look

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs