# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a django application, but when I try to start the server, I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'.
Here is my code in settings.py:

````
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu',
]`

```
````

---

Here is the project structure:
[My files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c3ef.jpg)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please show us your directory structure.

Comment: Is your app inside your project root? this app must be present in your project root where manage.py file is present.

Comment: @yxzlwz Added project structure

Comment: @Поля-Гречка : Alright then, your `menu` directory is in a wrong place. It should be a child directory of `Uptader_test`, at same level with `manage.py`

Comment: @yxzlws i created the folder in the correct location but i still get this error

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your project's urls.py file if you didn't have done yet:

```
from django.urls import path, include    
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('menu.urls')),
]
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614960/add-urls-from-a-django-app)here is the same answer available it might help you